# Binning a pandas column based on quantiles

Tags: python, pandas, quantile

I have a pandas data frame 'train' as

```
Name   Comb   Sales
Joy     A123   102
John    A134   112
Aby     A123   140
Amit    A123   190
Andrew  A134   210
Pren    A123   109
Abry    A134   230
Hulk    A134   188  
...
```

For each unique Comb I want to find the 25% quantiles of the corresponding sales and create respective bins. For example if you create 25% quantile bins for the sales of Comb='A123' you will get (102.00 107.25 124.50 152.50 190.00). Now I want to bin my sales for all Comb='A123' using these quantiles. My resulting data would be

```
Name   Comb   Sales  Bin  Bin_Low  Bin_High
Joy     A123   102    1    102     107.25
John    A134   112    1    112     169
Aby     A123   140    3    124.50  152.50
Amit    A123   190    4    152.90  190
Andrew  A134   210    3    199     215
Pren    A123   109    2    107.25  124.50
Abry    A134   230    4    215     230
Hulk    A134   188    2    169     199
```

I created the below code but my final data frame does not come out in the right format.

```
     quant = pd.DataFrame()
     i = ''
     for  i  in train.comb.unique():    
     a=pd.qcut(train[train.comb == i ]['Sales'], 4,duplicates='drop')
     df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(a))
     comp=pd.concat([train[train.combo == i ],df], axis=1)
     quant=quant.append(comp)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please check your formatting and, if is possible, share your `df ` as `df.to_dict()` so the problem it's easier to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `qcut` on your dataframe, grouped by the `Comb`. Then, assign the left side to a `Bin_low` column and the right to a `Bin_max`. Note that the qcut has an open interval on the `left` side, so the values will be a tiny bit off of your desired output, but essentially the same:

```
intervals = train.groupby('Comb')['Sales'].transform(pd.qcut, 4)

train['Bin_low'] = pd.IntervalIndex(intervals).left
train['Bin_high'] = pd.IntervalIndex(intervals).right

>>> train
     Name  Comb  Sales  Bin_low  Bin_high
0     Joy  A123    102  101.999    107.25
1    John  A134    112  111.999    169.00
2     Aby  A123    140  124.500    152.50
3    Amit  A123    190  152.500    190.00
4  Andrew  A134    210  199.000    215.00
5    Pren  A123    109  107.250    124.50
6    Abry  A134    230  215.000    230.00
7    Hulk  A134    188  169.000    199.00
```

Comment: Thanks! could you also please modify your code to have the bin column as indicated in the question?

Comment: You can add: `train['Bin'] = train.groupby('Comb')['Sales'].transform(pd.qcut, 4,labels=False)+1`